# Multithreading server receives data from clients java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm working on project where i have a multithreading server who handle multiple clients but there are two type of clients(administrator and conferencier) and i'm stuck with a problem i have created a server and when a client is accepted there are condition if the client is administrator or conferencier beacause each of this different clients has his own handler classe (function) but the code work only with the first condition it's not working for both

My server code:

```
try {

  ss = new ServerSocket(portnb);
  System.out.println("le serveur wainting for client");

} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

while (true) {
  try {        
    clientsocket = ss.accept();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientsocket.getInputStream()));
    if (in.readLine().equals("calculeID"))// administrator function{
      Handler h = new Handler(clientsocket);
      new Thread(h).start();
      System.out.println("administrator is here ");
      in.close();
    }else{  
      if (in.readLine().equals("start"))// conferencier function{            
        Handlerconf hc= new Handlerconf(clientsocket);
        new Thread (hc).start();
        System.out.println("conferencier is here ");
        in.close();
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
  ss.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each call to `readLine()` reads a **new** line. Call `readLine()` **once**, and store the result in a variable. Then test the value of this variable.